# 'Moved Temporarily' error Google Latitude API

Tags: jakarta-ee, post, oauth-2.0

So this seems to be a common error for people to see, but I can't work out how to solve it!
I'm trying to write a simple Java EE app (using JBoss v7.1) in Eclipse, and have had what seems to be no end of trouble! I'm finally down to what seems to be the final hurdle; obtaining the access token.

I'm programming it 'manually' as it were; setting up the http post myself:

```
    @WebServlet("/callback") //user has accepted the authentication, and the auth code is sent to this url
    public class CallBackServlet extends HttpServlet {

            //my vars
            private static final String clientId = "123.apps.googleusercontent.com";
            private static final String clientSecret = "123abc";
            private static final String redirectUri = "http://localhost:8080/WebProjectA/callback";

        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

                String code = request.getParameter("code"); //grabs the auth code

                //set up http post
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient( );
                String postUrl = "/o/oauth2/token"; 
                HostConfiguration hf=new HostConfiguration();
                hf.setHost("accounts.google.com"); //problems start here. Anything other than "accounts.google.com" results in an 'unknown host' exception

        PostMethod postData = new PostMethod(postUrl);      
        postData.setHostConfiguration(hf);

                //add post message parameters
        postData.addParameter(URLEncoder.encode("code"), URLEncoder.encode(code));
        postData.addParameter(URLEncoder.encode("client_id"), URLEncoder.encode(clientId));
        postData.addParameter(URLEncoder.encode("client_secret"), URLEncoder.encode(clientSecret));
        postData.addParameter(URLEncoder.encode("redirect_uri"), URLEncoder.encode(redirectUri));
        postData.addParameter(URLEncoder.encode("grant_type"), URLEncoder.encode("authorization_code"));

        client.executeMethod(postData);
        String postResponseb = postData.getResponseBodyAsString( );
        out.println(postResponseb); //print the info to the browser
        postData.releaseConnection( );
            }
    }
```

The redirect message wants me to use a 'https://accounts.google.com' host, but when I put anything other than 'accounts.google.com' as the host, I get an unknown host exception.

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the protocal while calling `hf.setHost("accounts.google.com",-1,"HTTPS");` method. see the java docs. by default protocol in http.

Comment: you may need to use an overloaded method hf.setHost() based on apache http client api version that you are using.